# Twitter widget for website doesn't work

Tags: twitter, web, widget

I'm trying to create a Twitter feed widget to put on a website and it doesn't seem to work.
I tried to create it at: https://twitter.com/settings/widgets/new and the code it spit out is

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/AniaMorton" data-widget-id="246615272616755200">Tweets by @AniaMorton</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

but all I see on my website is a link to "Tweets by @AniaMorton". Why is this?
The link of the website is: http://athleticedgefitness.com

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That throws the error *Widget not whitelisted for domain 'athleticedgefitness.com'*.

Given that it works on http://www.athleticedgefitness.com/ when you setup the widget you specified it was to run on *www.athleticedgefitness.com* which is treated differently from *athleticedgefitness.com*.

Review your setup and add *athleticedgefitness.com* to the list of allowed domains.

Comment: I tried that, I added http://athleticedgefitness.com/ and athleticedgefitness.com but still doesn't seem to work for http://athleticedgefitness.com/ ... :(